# Multiple image uploads in React

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am building an e-commerce mobile app with react native, and I want to make it possible for the users to upload multiple images of a product, but I don't know the best package to install for this to work, I don't even know if I should do it from scratch, this question is more like an advise question just to guide me, Please any help will be really great, Thanks

Comment: Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone

Comment: It doesn't work with react native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [react-native-image-cropper-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) and it cuts it. It allows `multiple picking`, `base64`, `cropping` among others.

To pick multiple you can do as follows:

```
pickMultiple() {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
            multiple: true,
            waitAnimationEnd: false,
            includeExif: true,
            forceJpg: true,
        }).then(images => {
            this.setState({
                imagesArray: images.map(i => {  
                    console.log('received image', i);
                    return {uri: i.path, width: i.width, height: i.height, mime: i.mime};
                })
            });
        }).catch(e => alert(e));
    }
```

Comment: Please what's includeExif, what's the use of exif data

Comment: You can set `includeExif` to true if you are interested in image metadata such as creation date, camera model, dimensions, color mode etc